# Not able to update mapping in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have been trying to update my mapping but not able to do that. Majorly this question is related to updating the nested part. Suppose there is a field "Anand" which contains a field "hello"

```
{
  "properties": {
    "anand": {
      "hello": {
        "type": "short"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I am getting the error

```
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "No type specified for field [anand]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "No type specified for field [anand]"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Current Mapping is

```
{
  "anandschool" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "anand" : {
          "type" : "nested"
        },
        "doc" : {
          "properties" : {
            "properties" : {
              "properties" : {
                "shop_tier" : {
                  "type" : "long"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "message" : {
          "type" : "byte"
        },
        "properties" : {
          "properties" : {
            "shop_tier" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "shop_type" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "shop" : {
          "type" : "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I even created a nested type anand so that it can work

```
{
  "properties": {
    "anand": {
        "type": "nested"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self Answer

When updating mapping for nested things need to update properties of the nested field.

For above example update by

```
  "properties": {
    "anand": {
     "properties":{
      "hello": {
        "type": "short"
      }
     }
    }
  }
}
```

THough This will not work inside a field which is nested.Ex if anand type was "nested", it would not work. If anyone knows solution for that let me know.